# What does this crescent shaped icon mean and do?

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, notification-icons

This icon popped up on my screen today. I don't know how or what it does and how to remove it. I have a Redmi 4a.

[image]

Does anyone know to remove it?

Comment: Do you have night mode turned on or an app with night mode (screen overlay)?

Comment: @firelord don't know. How do I check that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's **DND** (Do Not Disturb)

> DND is  a feature which after enabling you aren’t disturbed by
>   notifications or other forms of incoming communication. Do Not
>   Disturb(DND) can be set automatically or manually based on a few
>   parameters that you control.

[image]

One way to disable DND is to  drag down your Notification Panel and select DND from the different toggles.

Alternatively navigate to Settings >> Do Not Disturb and disable it.

Acknowledgements

[DND (Do Not Disturb) - A Nice Way To Block Unwanted Notifications!!](http://c.mi.com/thread-26216-1-1.html)